# Is there any form to set a 100% of horizontal size for TextCtrl in Toolbar?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Is there any form to set a 100% of horizontal size for TextCtrl in Toolbar?

Because I have been looking for about this in the documentation and I did not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do that in a normal toolbar. However, you can easily just roll your own toolbar by using a horizontally oriented BoxSizer and adding the necessary widgets to it. Then you can add the text control with the correct proportion and the `wx.EXPAND` flag.